# How to install Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 (just announced in Google I/O)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the file (Windows for me) from the [build download links page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-preview-1).

After downloading the zip file and unzipping it - i dont see a clear setup file to run. Where is the installer?

[image]

Comment: you dont need to install. run studio.exe or studio64.exe under .../bin/

Comment: Yea, figured that a bit later. Silly me. that's the answer to this bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open android-studio/bin/studio.exe or studio64.exe

Answer (score 1):

go to bin folder and click on studio.exe or studio64.exe